# How can I check progress on an EIN application?

Tags: united-states, irs, small-business, ein

How can I resolve my case when the IRS doesn't provide a mechanism for me to obtain updates?

I registered an LLC and would like an EIN to open bank accounts.

I filed an SS-4 in May.

The SS-4 was returned requesting the Certificate of Incorporation.

I faxed this to the IRS at the end of June.

Since then I've heard nothing.

I called the IRS today and the phone system said that the IRS is too busy to deal with calls requesting updates on EINs.

I'm frustrated because I'm somewhat in limbo assuming my case is pending but unable to find another means for contacting the IRS.

I would value suggestions.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like you've covered the options. There's an [online SS-4](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/apply-for-an-employer-identification-number-ein-online), but since you've already submitted it, it doesn't matter anymore.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment. Yes, I'm really unsure whether I've an alternative option. I've been swallowed by the system :-(

Comment: Did you try submitting a new one online?  I don't think it matters that you did a paper one already.

Comment: For some reason, I was unable to use the online form; I received an error code and instructions to call! But, I could try resubmitting the original form w/ the Certificate of Incorporation. That's a good idea, thanks!